# Linq to twitter wp8 implementation

Tags: c#, linq, twitter, windows-phone-8, linq-to-twitter

I’m trying to get Linq to twitter to work on a wp8 App, i’ve looked throughout the available documentation and was not able to figure this out, when trying the [demos](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt) (which the author says works for wp8) i get errors.
Im using the ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer, my intention is just to be able to read the public tweets (not be able to log in and send tweets).

MainPage.cs

```
public MainPage()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();
     UserTweetsWidget = new UserTweetsViewModel("xxxxxxxx", 20);
     this.DataContext = this;
}
```

TweetModel.cs

```
public class TweetModel
{
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string PublicationDate { get; set; }
}
```

UserTweetsViewModel.cs

```
public class UserTweetsViewModel
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TweetModel> Tweets { get; set; }

    private const string consumerKey = “xxxxxxx”;
    private const string consumerSecret = “xxxxxx”;
    private const string twitterAccessToken = “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”;
    private const string twitterAccessTokenSecret = “xxxxxxxxxx”;

    public UserTweetsViewModel(string userName, int count)
    {
        String _n= userName;
        int _c= count;
        InitializeAsync(_n, _c);
    }

    private async Task InitializeAsync(string userName, int count)
    {
        this.Label = string.Format("Tweets by @{0}", userName);
        Tweets = await GetTwitterUserTimeLine(userName, count);
    }

    private async Task<ObservableCollection<TweetModel>> GetTwitterUserTimeLine(string userName, int count)
    {
        ObservableCollection<TweetModel> result = new ObservableCollection<TweetModel>();

        var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
                OAuthToken= twitterAccessToken,
                OAuthTokenSecret= twitterAccessTokenSecret
            }
        };

        await auth.AuthorizeAsync();             
        TwitterContext twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

       var tweets = twitterCtx.Status.Where(tweet => tweet.ScreenName == userName && tweet.Type == StatusType.Home).Take(count).ToList();

        foreach (var item in tweets)
        {               
            TweetModel tweet = new TweetModel()
            {
                Text = item.Text,
                ScreenName = item.User.Name,
                UserName = "@" + item.ScreenName,
                PublicationDate = Convert.ToString(item.CreatedAt),
                Image = item.User.ProfileImageUrl                      
            };
            result.Add(tweet);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 2):

The problem, i think, is you aren't awaiting the AuthorizeAsync method.

First, you need to convert your `GetTwitterUserTimeLine` into an `async` method:

```
private async Task<ObservableCollection<TweetModel>> GetTwitterUserTimeLine(string userName, int count)
```

Then, you can call `auth.AuthorizeAsync`, awaiting the call:

```
await auth.AuthorizeAsync();
```

This way, the method waits until the authorization is completed, before continue execution.

**UPDATE:**

To call this method from your viewmodel, You can create a new method in the ViewModel, called InitializeAsync:

```
private async Task InitializeAsync()
```

In that method, call the GetTwitterUserTimeLine this way:

```
Tweets = await GetTwitterUserTimeLine(username, count);
```

Finally, you need to call the InitializeAsync Method from your viewmodel constructor, and it's going to work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i just tried that, but i get an error
`Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<LinqToTwitter_Test.ViewModels.TweetModel>>' 
to 
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<LinqToTwitter_Test.ViewModels.TweetModel>'`

Comment: You need to await the call to GetTwitterUserTimeLine also, to receive the ObservableCollection<TweetModel> and not the task.

Comment: could u show me how to modify?
This is how i have the call
`public UserTweetsViewModel(string userName, int count)
        {
            this.Label = string.Format("Tweets by @{0}", userName);
            this.Tweets = GetTwitterUserTimeLine(userName, count);
        }`

Comment: well the call is going but now i get stuck the next line, that should be the response data `var tweets = twitterCtx.Status.Where(tweet => tweet.ScreenName == userName && tweet.Type == StatusType.Home).Take(count).ToList();`
on the constructor i have `public UserTweetsViewModel(string userName, int count)
{
String _n= userName;
int _c= count;
InitializeAsync(_n, _c);
}`

Comment: What is the problem you are having now?

Comment: well nothing happens, it's not showing the tweets, i will update my post and show u the 3 classes i have

Comment: But, in the var tweets, after executing the query, are you getting any result?

Comment: no i'm not, that's where I'm stuck
I have updated my post to show the 3 classes

Comment: @BobMachine remove the ScreenName filter in the where clause. Home timeline only works on the authorized user. Also, you should use SingleUserAuthorizer because you're tweeting on behalf of a user. According to the documentation, ScreenName isn't an input parameter: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20the%20Home%20Timeline&referringTitle=Making%20Status%20Queries%20and%20Calls

Comment: @BobMachine If you just want to search for a user's tweets, use a Search query and then you can use ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Searching%20Twitter&referringTitle=Performing%20Searches%20and%20Finding%20Trends

Comment: @JoeMayo I removed the ScreenName filter and still nothing.
My intention is only to read the public timelines not to send tweets, my understanding was that ApplicationOnly was the mode for that, am i correct?

Comment: @BobMachine You have to look at the API you're using. If the API operates on behalf of a user, then ApplicationOnly won't work. You should get a TwitterQueryException if you were using try/catch. Also, at the bottom of each documented API call is a link to the Twitter API documentation that tells you which type of authorization is valid. Twitter doesn't offer an API for a 3rd party to retrieve another person's home timeline. The only option to get someone's home timeline is for that user to authorize your app to do so.

Comment: @JoeMayo using ur suggestion I'm able to get a search result, for tweets that match that query, but what i was trying to do, was to  get the public tweets, it was based on this example [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Twitter-widget-in-Windows-837bc147/view/SourceCode) but that is for w8 NOT wp8 that's what i was trying to do, i d/l the demos on codeplex but just got errors and was not able to use any as a starting point.
So to get a user public tweets u say i need singleUserAuthorizer? Are there any working examples?

Comment: Well, i think you need to take a deep look to the API. Now, your question about having a working example is complete... now your code works correctly

Comment: @JosueYeray ur 'kinda' right, I'm able to retrieve tweets but based on a search query not of a particular user, which is what i want to do.
Hopefuly JoeMayo can shed some light on this.
But thank you very much JosueYeray u have been very helpful, i just need a little extra push :)

Comment: @BobMachine There are a couple differences between the link you provided and your code. The example was for the User timeline, but yours was for the Home timeline. That was an older version of LINQ to Twitter and the new version uses async. There's a Linq2TwitterDemos_WindowsPhone sample in the downloadable source code that shows proper syntax and the Linq2TwitterDemos_Console project has demos for every API call.

Comment: @BobMachine Thanks for providing that link. I added a comment to the sample to let everyone know that the latest version of LINQ to Twitter, v3.0, is async.

Comment: @JoeMayo I do stand corrected, I'm trying to get the User timeline.
That's the thing i d/l the Linq2TwitterDemos_WindowsPhone but i can't build it it keeps saying references missing but i have set NuGet to enable restore, but still nothing

Comment: @JoeMayo Im just trying to get the user timeline for a specific user at a time, i have tried all i can think of and i can't get it to work, like i said i can't get the demo to work i get reference error (i have cleaned/rebuild) and nothing.
what i have is posted in my question, could you tell me what changes i need to make to get it to work, please.

Comment: @BobMachine Read the name of the assembly and version where you have the error and add a reference. You could also create a new project and add LINQ to Twitter via NuGet and then use the code from the demo. The solution was built with VS 2013. I can look at LINQ to Twitter code and point you in the right direction, but I can't debug problems on your local machine. You need the basic knowledge of how to create a project in VS.

Comment: @JoeMayo I'm using VS Express 2012 for windows phone and it was causing some incompatibility but i have created a new solution and added the 2 projects and the demo is working now.
I have been able to "Perform search"and use the SingleUserAuthorizer code, how do i now get the User timeline for a specific user?
I'll just add it manually now but later add a textbox to get user input.

Comment: @BobMachine The Twitter API (which LINQ to Twitter is based on) only offers the home timeline for whoever is the authorized user. If you aren't the authorized user, then you can fake it by manually building the home timeline yourself. Essentially, you have to manually do separate queries to get tweets (including retweets) for (1) the user, (2) all the user's followers, (3) and mentions of the user. I think that's everything that goes into a home timeline, but someone else might elaborate if I've forgotten. Then combine those lists and sort by date.

Comment: @JoeMayo what I'm trying to is exactly what is on [this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Twitter-widget-in-Windows-837bc147/view/SourceCode) but on windows phone 8, and this is done with linq to twitter too.
I just cannot figure out what the differences are, that's what I'm asking ur help with?
On that example I'm able to type a handle and get the public tweets for that handle and that's what I'm trying to do...

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?